# WPF - Handling events from user control in View Model

Tags: wpf, events, mvvm

I’m building a WPF application using MVVM pattern (both are new technologies for me). I use user controls for simple bits of reusable functionality that doesn’t contain business logic, and MVVM pattern to build application logic. Suppose a view contains my user control that fires events, and I want to add an event handler to that event. That event handler should be in the view model of the view, because it contains business logic. The question is – view and the view model are connected only by binding; how do I connect an event handler using binding? Is it even possible (I suspect not)? If not – how should I handle events from a control in the view model? Maybe I should use commands or INotifyPropertyChanged?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Generally speaking, it is a good MVVM-practice to avoid code in code behind, as would be the case if you use events in your user controls. So when possible, use `INotifyPropertyChanged` and `ICommand`.

With that said, depending on your project and how pragmatic you are, some times it makes more sense to use the control's code behind.

I have at a few occasions used something like this:

```
private void textBox1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    MyViewModel vm = this.DataContext as MyViewModel;
    vm.MethodToExecute(...);
}
```

You could also consider [Attached Command Behaviour](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/johngossman/the-attached-behavior-pattern), more info about this and implementations to find here:

[Firing a double click event from a WPF ListView item using MVVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1035023/firing-a-double-click-event-from-a-wpf-listview-item-using-mvvm)

Comment: Control should be reusable, so the code won't do - it ties the control to a specific view model. Commands... Probably not - they are more for user actions. INotifyPropertyChanged then?

Thanks :)

Comment: Hard to say for me without knowing more specifics. But I added in some links to related info

Comment: @Vitaly if you are worried about tying the View to the explicit ViewModel, you could wrap the ViewModel in an interface. I would look into Attached Command Behaviors they are becoming the accepted practice. Also, check out MVVMLight or Caliburn as a framework to assist in your MVVM work, it will make you life much easier.

Comment: Sorry for Necro-Threading but I've been fiddling with trying to get my events handled in my controller for awhile and at the line of which I call the function I get "System.NullReferenceException" from which I assume DataContext is empty and is trying to build my controller?

Comment: Would `((TypeOfControl)sender).DataContext` be an option to do it for individual controls and also to avoid cases where the `DataContext` is not directly in the window?