# Handle MainWindow events in ViewModel - WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, binding, model-binding

I want to handle Windows event like Closing, SourceInitialized in my viewModel. I don't want to handle them in my code behind. How can I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use an implementation like MVVM Light's `EventToCommand`, or use a Behavior to capture the events needed and pass an `ICommand` to the behavior. You can then raise the `Command.Execute` inside the behavior when the required event occurs and handle it in the VM after that.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on this please?

Comment: Very similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2927153/wpf-handling-events-from-user-control-in-view-model

Comment: I always use attached behaviours for that.  I also use an abstraction of the various windows functions like close, maximize, and so on so that the vm can be tested with a mock.  But overall, the attached behaviour is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use EventToCommand.

ViewModel:

```
public ICommand WindowClosing

{
    get
    {
        return new RelayCommand<CancelEventArgs>(
            (args) =>{
                });
    }
}
```

and in XAML:

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Closing">
        <command:EventToCommand Command="{Binding WindowClosing}" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```