# MVVM C# WPF binding mouse double click

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I want to copy the content of one text box to another text box by clicking the mouse.

How do I bind a mouse click event?

Comment: Can you describe the scenario of the mouse click a bit more. Does the mouse have to be in a specific area or on a certain control, or just any mouse click? Also are you wanting to simulate a click or a double click?

Comment: Maybe this answers your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1035023/firing-a-double-click-event-from-a-wpf-listview-item-using-mvvm/1510592#1510592

Answer (score 9):

This sample is for `RightClick`, but you can adjust the event according to your needs:

```
<TextBox>
    <TextBox.InputBindings>
        <MouseBinding Gesture="RightClick" Command="{Binding YourCommand}" />
    </TextBox.InputBindings>
</TextBox>
```

**Edit:** I uploaded on my SkyDrive a [sample app](http://sdrv.ms/M5prsj) that illustrates how to use this method in order to achieve exactly what you need. Please be advised that it will only work for .NET Framework 4+

Comment: Will this work?  I don't think you can use Binding like this...  It will complain that "A 'Binding' cannot be set on the 'Command' property of type 'MouseBinding'.  A 'Binding' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a Dependency Object.  What do you think?

Comment: Unfortunately it won't work due to this: http://connectppe.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/687703/mousebinding-doesnt-work-in-listview-and-treeview

Comment: OK, people, it will work only when targeting .NET 4. For previous versions it will throw the error specified by Ann Sanderson

Answer (score 3):

Want to add a behavior to a control ? Just use the [Ramora pattern](http://blog.lexique-du-net.com/index.php?post/2010/02/17/Use-AttachedProperties-to-add-behaviors-to-the-components) !

Comment: While I admit Ramora pattern's utility, I think its complexity is not suitable for what user456871 needs; there are other more simple solutions

Answer (score 2):

### Hope this helps

Use this code for `TreeView`

```
<TreeView commandBehaviors:MouseDoubleClick.Command="{Binding YourCommand}"
          commandBehaviors:MouseDoubleClick.CommandParameter="{Binding}"
          .../>
```

Use this code for `TreeViewItem`

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Projects}">
    <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="commandBehaviors:MouseDoubleClick.Command"
                    Value="{Binding YourCommand}"/>
            <Setter Property="commandBehaviors:MouseDoubleClick.CommandParameter"
                    Value="{Binding}"/>
        </Style>
    </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
</TreeView>
```

Use this code to create a new behavior `MouseDoubleClick`

```
public class MouseDoubleClick
{
    public static DependencyProperty CommandProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Command",
        typeof(ICommand),
        typeof(MouseDoubleClick),
        new UIPropertyMetadata(CommandChanged));

    public static DependencyProperty CommandParameterProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("CommandParameter",
                                            typeof(object),
                                            typeof(MouseDoubleClick),
                                            new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

    public static void SetCommand(DependencyObject target, ICommand value)
    {
        target.SetValue(CommandProperty, value);
    }

    public static void SetCommandParameter(DependencyObject target, object value)
    {
        target.SetValue(CommandParameterProperty, value);
    }
    public static object GetCommandParameter(DependencyObject target)
    {
        return target.GetValue(CommandParameterProperty);
    }

    private static void CommandChanged(DependencyObject target, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Control control = target as Control;
        if (control != null)
        {
            if ((e.NewValue != null) && (e.OldValue == null))
            {
                control.MouseDoubleClick += OnMouseDoubleClick;
            }
            else if ((e.NewValue == null) && (e.OldValue != null))
            {
                control.MouseDoubleClick -= OnMouseDoubleClick;
            }
        }
    }

    private static void OnMouseDoubleClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Control control = sender as Control;
        ICommand command = (ICommand)control.GetValue(CommandProperty);
        object commandParameter = control.GetValue(CommandParameterProperty);
        command.Execute(commandParameter);
    }
}
```

Comment: Great answer, thanks! Note: In the ItemContainerStyle, you'll probably have to use the Command binding `{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.YourCommand}`, assuming the top level control is a Window (switch to UserControl or whatever is appropriate otherwise)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are inventing a new behaviour for your textbox  :)

I would just consider if the users of your program understands and likes this behaviour.

Maybe it is easier to understand the funcionality if it is just a button you have to click - it is also faster to implement :)

Comment: +1. I hate apps that try to be *too* innovative with their interaction schemes

Answer (score 0):

I think you could bind mouse gestures to commands. Take a look at this: http://www.thejoyofcode.com/Invoking_a_Command_on_a_Double_Click_or_other_Mouse_Gesture.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly you're wanting to bind to.

There is no readily available `MouseClick` event as far as i'm aware.

the `Click` event as you'd find on a `Button` is inherited from `ButtonBase` and is not readily available on most controls.

`MouseDoubleClick` is inherited from `Control` and available on anythning deriving from it.

in your example it sounds like a simple `Button` with its `Click` event handled might do the trick.

To bind to the click event, you just need to specify the event handler for the event in the `Button`.

Something like:

XAML:

```
<TextBox Name=TextBoxOne />
<TextBox Name=TextBoxTwo />

<Button Click="CopyTextButton_Click"/>
```

And in your code behind:

```
void CopyTextButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //Copy the text and anything else you need done
}
```

Otherwise if this is a more specialised scenario, you might want to investigate using a `UserControl` or as AndrewS answered above, a Command.

Hope it helps.

Comment: ok thx. im thinking of putting a button 'behind' the textbox (custom textbox + button user control) to achieve this. So when the user clicks on the text, the button gets the event... thx guys for the help. i will try this out.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this by creating a new behavior.

```
<TextBox 
    MouseDoubleClick="SelectAddress" 
    GotKeyboardFocus="SelectAddress" 
    PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="SelectivelyIgnoreMouseButton" />
```

Here's the code behind:

```
private void SelectAddress(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    TextBox tb = (sender as TextBox);
    if (tb != null)
    {
        tb.SelectAll();
    }

}

private void SelectivelyIgnoreMouseButton(object sender, 
        MouseButtonEventArgs e)

{

    TextBox tb = (sender as TextBox);
    if (tb != null)
    {
         if (!tb.IsKeyboardFocusWithin)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            tb.Focus();
        }
    }
}
```

Please update this snippet according to your need.