# Attached Behavior to execute command for ListViewItem

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am trying to use an attached behavior to execute a command in my ViewModel when the user Double Clicks on the list item.

I have reviewed a number of articles on the subject, and tried creating a simple test application but am still having problems eg.
[Firing a double click event from a WPF ListView item using MVVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1035023/firing-a-double-click-event-from-a-wpf-listview-item-using-mvvm)

My simple test ViewModel has 2 collections, one that returns a list of strings and the other that returns a List of ListViewItem types

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public ViewModel()
    {
        Stuff = new ObservableCollection<ListViewItem>
                    {
                        new ListViewItem { Content = "item 1" },
                        new ListViewItem { Content = "item 2" }
                    };

        StringStuff = new ObservableCollection<string> { "item 1", "item 2" };
    }

    public ObservableCollection<ListViewItem> Stuff { get; set; }

    public ObservableCollection<string> StringStuff { get; set; }

    public ICommand Foo
    {
        get
        {
            return new DelegateCommand(this.DoSomeAction);
        }
    }

    private void DoSomeAction()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Command Triggered");
    }
}
```

Here is the attached property which is like may other examples you see:

```
public class ClickBehavior
{
    public static DependencyProperty DoubleClickCommandProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("DoubleClick",
               typeof(ICommand),
               typeof(ClickBehavior),
               new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, new PropertyChangedCallback(ClickBehavior.DoubleClickChanged)));

    public static void SetDoubleClick(DependencyObject target, ICommand value)
    {
        target.SetValue(ClickBehavior.DoubleClickCommandProperty, value);
    }

    public static ICommand GetDoubleClick(DependencyObject target)
    {
        return (ICommand)target.GetValue(DoubleClickCommandProperty);
    }

    private static void DoubleClickChanged(DependencyObject target, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ListViewItem element = target as ListViewItem;
        if (element != null)
        {
            if ((e.NewValue != null) && (e.OldValue == null))
            {
                element.MouseDoubleClick += element_MouseDoubleClick;
            }
            else if ((e.NewValue == null) && (e.OldValue != null))
            {
                element.MouseDoubleClick -= element_MouseDoubleClick;
            }
        }
    }

    static void element_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        UIElement element = (UIElement)sender;
        ICommand command = (ICommand)element.GetValue(ClickBehavior.DoubleClickCommandProperty);
        command.Execute(null);
    }
}
```

In my main window, I have defined the style which sets the attached behaviour and binds to the Foo command

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="listViewItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
        <Setter Property="local:ClickBehavior.DoubleClick" Value="{Binding Foo}"/>                 
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

Works fine when ListViewItems are defined:

```
<!-- Works -->
<Label Grid.Row="2" Content="DoubleClick click behaviour:"/>        
<ListView Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource listViewItemStyle}">
    <ListViewItem Content="Item 3" />
    <ListViewItem Content="Item 4" />
</ListView>
```

This works too, when bound to the list of type ListViewItem:

```
<!-- Works when items bound are of type ListViewItem -->
<Label Grid.Row="3" Content="DoubleClick when bound to ListViewItem:"/>        
  <ListView Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource listViewItemStyle}" ItemsSource="{Binding Stuff}">        
 </ListView>
```

But this doesn't:

```
<!-- Does not work when items bound are not ListViewItem -->
<Label Grid.Row="4" Content="DoubleClick when bound to string list:"/>
  <ListView Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource listViewItemStyle}" ItemsSource="{Binding StringStuff}">
</ListView>
```

In the output window you see the error, but finding it difficult to understand what is wrong.
*System.Windows.Data Error: 39 : BindingExpression path error: 'Foo' property not found on 'object' ''String' (HashCode=785742638)'. BindingExpression:Path=Foo; DataItem='String' (HashCode=785742638); target element is 'ListViewItem' (Name=''); target property is 'DoubleClick' (type 'ICommand')*

So my quesion is: How can you get the Command wired up correctly to each ListViewItem when you bind your ListView to a list of Model objects?

Thanks.

Comment: This was very useful! For added reusability, I changed ListViewItem element = target as ListViewItem; to Control element = target as Control;

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that the `DataContext` for the `Binding` is the string.  Since there is no `Foo` property of the string class, you are getting an error.  This doesn't happen in the other cases because they inherit their `DataContext` from the parent (this doesn't happen for automatically generated containers for data items - their `DataContext` is the data item).

If you change your binding to use the parent `ListView`'s `DataContext`, it should work fine:

```
Value="{Binding DataContext.Foo, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}}"
```

Comment: Thank you for the swift answer, Abe. You are a star, have been trying to figure this out for far too long.

Comment: No problem Paul. The binding errors are really cryptic, and sometimes it just takes a fresh pair of eyes to see what is going on!