# Compile error in Listview XAML code related to binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, binding

I have defined in XAML a list view, see following fragment:

```
<Grid>
    <Button Content="_Generate List ..." Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,12,12" Name="buttonGenerateLists" 
            VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Click="ButtonGenerateListsClick" Width="108" Grid.Column="1" />
    <ListView HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="275,34,13,96" Name="listViewPatches" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" SelectionMode="Extended" 
              VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" AlternationCount="1" GotFocus="ListViewPatchGotFocus" 
              MouseDoubleClick="{Binding Path=EditSelectedItemCommand}" SelectedItem="{Binding IsSelected}">
```

And I get the following compile error:

> Error 1   MouseDoubleClick="{Binding Path=EditSelectedItemCommand}" is
>   not valid. '{Binding Path=EditSelectedItemCommand}' is not a valid
>   event handler method name. Only instance methods on the generated or
>   code-behind class are valid. Line 12 Position
>   19.   G:\Data\Eigen\Informatica\KorgKronosTools\KorgKronosTools\PcgWindow.xaml    12  19  PcgTools

(note: line 12 is the last line in the fragment above).

I guess I did not set the data context right, however in my code behind the following fragment is coded:

```
public PcgWindow(MainWindow mainWindow, string pcgFileName, PcgMemory pcgMemory)
{
    InitializeComponent();

    _mainWindow = mainWindow;
    _viewModel = new PcgViewModel(mainWindow.ViewModel);

    ...


    DataContext = _viewModel;
```

And I defined the binding itself in the viewmodel:

```
    ICommand _editSelectedItemCommand;
    public ICommand EditSelectedItemCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return _editSelectedItemCommand ?? (_editSelectedItemCommand = new RelayCommand(param => EditSelectedItem(),
                param => CanExecuteEditSelectedItem()));
        }
    }
```

Can someone help me to fix the compile error?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot bind events, only commands, you would need to specify a method name which is defined in code-behind as the error notes.

e.g.

```xml
MouseDoubleClick="OnMouseDoubleClick"
```

```
private void OnMouseDoubleClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Do something
}
```

If you must use a command you can use certain libraries like `Interactivity` (from the [Blend SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=10801)) which allow you to execute a command when an event is fired. e.g.

```
<ListView ...>
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDoubleClick">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding EditSelectedItemCommand}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Thank you, it works ... I used the commands for buttons, tool bar etc, but this does not work for a double click in a list view.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification ... I might use that method to clean up the code behind code (and I already have implemented the command itself).

Answer (score 2):

In order to bind the double click event to a command you'll need to use Blend's interaction triggers as discussed here: [WPF: How to bind a command to the ListBoxItem using MVVM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545187/wpf-how-to-bind-a-command-to-the-listboxitem-using-mvvm).

My example is:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="CustomerTemplate" DataType="{x:Type ViewModel:Customer}">
            <ContentControl>
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDoubleClick">
                        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DoubleClickCommand}" />
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </ContentControl>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Customers}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource CustomerTemplate}" />
</Grid>


public class Customer : ViewModelBase
{
    public Customer()
    {
        DoubleClickCommand = new RelayCommand(DoubleClick);    
    }

    private void DoubleClick()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("double click");
    }

    private string _name;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { Set(() => Name, ref _name, value); }
    }

    public ICommand DoubleClickCommand { get; private set; }
}
```