# How to use WPF DataGridRow events with Interaction.Triggers / MVVM EventToCommand

Tags: wpf, mvvm-light, wpfdatagrid, eventtocommand

The MVVMLight `EventToCommand` can be used to fire an `ICommand` on your viewmodel quite easily.

```
<DataGrid>
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
            <GalaSoft_MvvmLight_Command:EventToCommand
                Command="{Binding ProductSelectionChangedCommand, Mode=OneWay}    "
                CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItems, ElementName=gridProducts}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</DataGrid>
```

In this instance the `SelectionChanged` event belongs to [`DataGrid`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid_events), and the `Interaction.Triggers` xaml is nested directly inside `DataGrid`.

I cannot figure out how to do the same when the event is a `DataGridRow` (which has its own [events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridrow_events) for each row).

I managed to do this, but it involves a handler function which I'd like to avoid :

```
<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <EventSetter Event="DataGridRow.MouseEnter" 
                         Handler="Row_MouseEnter"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

In the `Row_MouseEnter` event (on my .xaml.cs file) I just 'find the command' on the ViewModel and trigger it programatically.

I'd really like to know if there's a way of doing the same directly with `Interaction.Triggers`

(FYI: What I'm doing is I have a panel above the grid which displays details of the row that the mouse is over before clicking on it - which triggers a detail view).

Answer (score 2):

Yeah you can directly bind to the command in your ViewModel by creating your own custom `behaviour class` and using it in xaml file. These links might get you started - [Binding using interactivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647815/how-to-add-a-blend-behavior-in-a-style-setter/4779168#4779168) and [Binding through interaction in MVVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545187/wpf-how-to-bind-a-command-to-the-listboxitem-using-mvvm)