# Trigger ListViewItem Command

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, triggers

I have the following ItemsControl which handles the display of items added to it:

```
 <ControlTemplate x:Key="MyItemsControlTemplate">
    <ItemsControl  x:Name="MyItemsControl" ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type mynameSpace:MyClass}}, Path=ItemsSource}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <WrapPanel.Resources>                                    
                        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MyCustomClass}">
                            <Button Command="{Binding}">
                                <TextBlock  Text="{Binding Path=DisplayValue}"/>
                            </Button>
                        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>                                 
                    </WrapPanel.Resources>
                </WrapPanel>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    </ItemsControl>
</ControlTemplate>
```

You can see that the Button has a Command="{Binding}" which handles the click event and calls a command.

Now I want to also use a ListView to display the same items and handle the click event.  I see from this link [WPF: How to bind a command to the ListBoxItem using MVVM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545187/wpf-how-to-bind-a-command-to-the-listboxitem-using-mvvm) that I have to use Interaction.Triggers so I have did the following:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="MyListViewControlTemplate">
    <ListView Name="MyListView" ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type mynameSpace:MyClass}}, Path=ItemsSource}">

        <ListView.View>
            <GridView >
                <GridViewColumn Header="Details" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=DisplayValue}"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>

        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonUp">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding}"></i:InvokeCommandAction>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>

    </ListView>
</ControlTemplate>
```

The items display properly in the ListView so I know the binding is correct for the text display but I find that the click handler for the ListView does not fire the command like the Button object does.
Any ideas?

How

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should apply the interaction trigger to an element within the `ListView`. You could use a `CellTemplate` with a `TextBlock` that you apply the interaction trigger to:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="MyListViewControlTemplate">
    <ListView Name="MyListView" ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type mynameSpace:MyClass}}, Path=ItemsSource}">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView >
                <GridViewColumn Header="Details">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayValue}">
                                        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                            <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonUp">
                                                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding}"></i:InvokeCommandAction>
                                            </i:EventTrigger>
                                        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                            </TextBlock>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: Thank you this has fixed my problem. I next want to have 2 Columns in my datagrid so I have used your method and added two inner TextBlocks with Interaction.Triggers.  Is there a way I can wrap the whole item in a single trigger? I find that if the I click on the row to the right of a textbox the event does not fire.

Comment: Unfortunately you cannot use an interaction trigger in a style. An alternative may be to use an attached behaviour that invokes the command: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28959/Introduction-to-Attached-Behaviors-in-WPF