# Mouse event on transparent background

Tags: wpf, background, mouseevent, transparent

I have create several canvas with transparent background and wanna make some move event on it.

However, I found that all mouse event (e.g. MouseLeftButtonDown) cannot function of the background of the canvas is Null or Transparent. But if I set the background to some solid color (say, red or blue), the mouse event function well.

Why?

Could I make the mouse event function properly with transparent background?

Thank you!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I'm not sure why you get the results you get but it should work fine when the background is transparent (i.e. you explicitly set it to [Brushes.Transparent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.brushes.transparent.aspx), either through XAML or code). If it is null, WPF will not include it in hit testing, and thus it won't be eligible for mouse events.

See e.g. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752097.aspx (*A visual object that is transparent can also be hit test.*)

Most likely you have another UIElement in your element tree that is capturing [and handling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747183.aspx) the mouse event before your canvas sees it (i.e. by setting e.Handled to `true`)

Answer (score 13):

`Transparent` DOES react to mouse events, that's the whole point of it, are you sure that you are even hitting the canvas?

Here's a XAML-only example:

```
  <Border Width="300" Height="300" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
    <Canvas Background="Transparent">
        <Canvas.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Canvas.MouseLeftButtonDown">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{x:Static Brushes.Red}"/>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Canvas.Triggers>
    </Canvas>
  </Border>
```

If you set the `Background` to `null`, either explicity or implicitly by removing the property it will no longer react.

Answer (score 9):

Note that there is a difference in setting the background to transparent as opposed to not setting it (or setting it to null). My experience is that hit-testing works on transparent, but not on a null background.