# How to detect if Window's Background is null?

Tags: c#, wpf, background, null, imagesource

My app has switch-backgrounds option, so I'd like to check whether my Mainwindow's Background's ImageSource is nulled (then I'll set it to the default Background), the problem is I can't reach it through `this.Background.ImageSource`, because there's no such option. Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to hit detect on a null or transparent background](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15169358/how-to-hit-detect-on-a-null-or-transparent-background)

Comment: Excuse me but this is code-behind question, not XAML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could cast the Background to an ImageBrush using the `as` operator and check whether you got a null reference back:

```
ImageBrush brush = this.Background as ImageBrush;
if(brush == null || brush.ImageSource == null)
{
    //no ImageBrush set as the Background...
}
```

Comment: If the Background property has been set to an ImageBrush the cast will succeed, i.e. you will get a reference to the ImageBrush back, and if it hasn't you will get a null reference back. It's as simple as that: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt.aspx