# How to put an auto show panel over a LibVLCSharp.WPF.VideoView?

Tags: c#, wpf, libvlcsharp

I'm writing a WPF desktop application, with some video playback functions. I decided to use LibVLCSharp.WPF to complete the playback task.

Xaml code:

```
<UserControl ...
             xmlns:vlc="clr-namespace:LibVLCSharp.WPF;assembly=LibVLCSharp.WPF"
             ... >
    <vlc:VideoView VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Canvas VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" MouseEnter="Canvas_MouseEnter">
        </Canvas>
    </vlc:VideoView>
</UserControl>
```

It works fine with playing video, but when I tried to put some hidden controls inside `Canvas` (or any other type of `Panel` control) and change their visiblity with `MouseEnter` event, nothing happens.

While debugging, I found out that `MouseEnter` event can only fire when `Canvas` has at least one visible control as its child, and mouse pointer entered that visible control.

I have read the articles about "airspace issue". It seems nothing to do with me since I just want to draw a control layer exactly inside playback area.

Is there any way that I can put an auto show panel on VLC player, which only shows when mouse "hovered" over playback area?

Comment: seems related to https://code.videolan.org/videolan/LibVLCSharp/issues/267#note_48214 . Did you try to set a Background color?

Comment: The thing that you need to understand is that putting controls inside of the VideoView is really a hack. These controls are detached and placed in a window over the VideoView, which is why the event don't bubble

Comment: @cube45 I changed my panel's background to "#01000000", and it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem solved with hint from @cube45 . Thank you.

I changed `Background` of `Canvas` to something that "not so transparent".

Xaml code:

```
<Canvas Background="#01000000" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" MouseEnter="Canvas_MouseEnter">
</Canvas>
```

And mouse events worked. Tricky, but useful.

Comment: Transparent background is default value, and that was my problem. I guess LibVLCSharp library will treat completely transparent items as "something not exist" @cube45

Comment: I was asking that because there seems to be a difference between left by default, and set to Transparent explicitely, as per this thread : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7991314/mouse-event-on-transparent-background

Comment: @cube45 I tried it today and... it won't work. I set backgroud to transparent manually, then no mouse events can fire anymore.